# MediaWiki's file cache is ignored after migration

Tags: php, mysql, apache, caching, mediawiki

**Problem:** I have set up a *MediaWiki* with *file caching* enabled, but when I migrate the file cache to another MediaWiki, the cache is bypassed.

**Background:** I have set up `MediaWiki 1.26.2` with `apache2` as the front-end web server and `mariadb` as the MySQL database, populated with the Danish wikipedia.

I have enabled the [file cache](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:File_cache) to accelerate performance in `LocalSettings.php`:

```php
# Enable file caching.
$wgUseFileCache = true;
$wgFileCacheDirectory = "/tmp/wikicache";
$wgShowIPinHeader = false;

# Enable sidebar caching.
$wgEnableSidebarCache=true;

# Enable page compression.
$wgUseGzip = true;

# Disable pageview counters.
$wgUseGzip = true;

# Enable miser mode.
$wgMiserMode = true;
```

**Goal:** Migrate the file cache, which is located under `/tmp/wikicache`, to another MediaWiki server. This does not seem to work, as the cache is skipped.

---

**Use case:** node `server` hosts MediaWiki, where I have migrated (copied) the file cache from another MediaWiki server, as well as the same `LocalSettings.php`.

Here is a cached page:

```
root@server:~# find /tmp/ -name DNA*
/tmp/wikicache/3/39/DNA.html.gz
```

On another node, `client`, I use the [apache benchmark](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) `ab` to measure the connection time when requesting that page. **TL;DR;** only 10% of the requests succeed with a time of ~20 sec, which is roughly the time needed to query the database and retrieve the whole page.

```
root@client:~# ab -n 100 -c 10 http://172.16.100.3/wiki/index.php/DNA
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1528965 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 172.16.100.3 (be patient).....done
Server Software:        Apache/2.4.7
Server Hostname:        172.16.100.3
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /wiki/index.php/DNA
Document Length:        1184182 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   27.744 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        90
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 90, Exceptions: 0)
Total transferred:      118456568 bytes
HTML transferred:       118417968 bytes
Requests per second:    3.60 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2774.370 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       277.437 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          4169.60 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:   123 2743 7837.1    145   27743
Waiting:      118 2735 7835.6    137   27723
Total:        123 2743 7837.2    145   27744

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    145
  66%    165
  75%    168
  80%    170
  90%  24788
  95%  26741
  98%  27625
  99%  27744
 100%  27744 (longest request)
```

If I subsequently request again the same page, it is served in ~0.15 seconds. I observe the same performance even if I flush MySQL's cache with `RESET QUERY CACHE`:

```
root@client:~# ab -n 100 -c 10 http://172.16.100.3/wiki/index.php/DNA
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1528965 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 172.16.100.3 (be patient).....done


Server Software:        Apache/2.4.7
Server Hostname:        172.16.100.3
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /wiki/index.php/DNA
Document Length:        1184179 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   1.564 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        41
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 41, Exceptions: 0)
Total transferred:      118456541 bytes
HTML transferred:       118417941 bytes
Requests per second:    63.93 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       156.414 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       15.641 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          73957.62 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       0
Processing:   129  150  18.8    140     189
Waiting:      120  140  18.0    130     171
Total:        129  150  18.8    141     189

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    141
  66%    165
  75%    169
  80%    170
  90%    175
  95%    181
  98%    188
  99%    189
 100%    189 (longest request)
```

So, why isn't the file cache working when I migrate it to another MediaWiki server?

Comment: Make sure [`$wgFileCacheDepth`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgFileCacheDepth) matches. Also, shouldn't that be something like `/tmp/wikicache/view/3/39/DNA.html.gz`?

Comment: @Tgr Thanks for your suggestion; I tried it out setting `$wgFileCacheDepth = 2;` but I still have the same problem. Furthermore, there is no `view` folder in there, it's `$wgFileCacheDirectory/0/0a/Example.html` as the manual page you have linked suggests.

Comment: Can you try symlinking `$wgFileCacheDirectory/view` to `$wgFileCacheDirectory`? I have never used file cache and I am not familiar with the code, but at a glance, it does look for a subdirectory there. See `FileCacheBase` [L93](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/REL1_26/includes/cache/FileCacheBase.php#L93), [L75-L79](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/REL1_26/includes/cache/FileCacheBase.php#L75-L79), [L210](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/REL1_26/includes/cache/FileCacheBase.php#L210)...

Comment: ...[L59](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/REL1_26/includes/cache/HTMLFileCache.php#L59) and `MediaWiki` [L696](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/REL1_26/includes/MediaWiki.php#L696).

Comment: @Tgr Thank you for your suggestion, I symlinked `$wgFileCacheDirectory/view` to `$wgFileCacheDirectory` but still, it seems that the cache is still not functional. Again, this is on the first query of a page, as mentioned in the original post.